# Extract this json content with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

**Json data**

> ```
> $bb='{
>   "ParsedResults": [
>     {
>       "Overlay": {
>         "Lines": [
>           {
>             "LineText": "Amazon",
>             "Words": [
>               {
>                 "WordText": "Amazon",
>                 "Left": 59.999996185302734,
>                 "Top": 24.999998092651367,
>                 "Height": 20,
>                 "Width": 99.99999237060547
>               }
>             ],
>             "MaxHeight": 20,
>             "MinTop": 24.999998092651367
>           },
>           {
>             "LineText": "€860.53",
>             "Words": [
>               {
>                 "WordText": "€860.53",
>                 "Left": 59.999996185302734,
>                 "Top": 57.499996185302734,
>                 "Height": 20,
>                 "Width": 105.83332824707031
>               }
>             ],
>             "MaxHeight": 20,
>             "MinTop": 57.499996185302734
>           },
>           {
>             "LineText": "Marketplace New",
>             "Words": [
>               {
>                 "WordText": "Marketplace",
>                 "Left": 60.83333206176758,
>                 "Top": 89.16666412353516,
>                 "Height": 24.16666603088379,
>                 "Width": 151.66665649414062
>               },
>               {
>                 "WordText": "New",
>                 "Left": 220.8333282470703,
>                 "Top": 89.16666412353516,
>                 "Height": 19.16666603088379,
>                 "Width": 52.499996185302734
>               }
>             ],
>             "MaxHeight": 24.16666603088379,
>             "MinTop": 89.16666412353516
>           }
>         ],
>         "HasOverlay": true,
>         "Message": "Total lines: 3"
>       },
>       "FileParseExitCode": 1,
>       "TextOrientation": "0",
>       "ParsedText": "Amazon\n€860.53\nMarketplace New",
>       "ErrorMessage": "",
>       "ErrorDetails": ""
>     }
>   ],
>   "OCRExitCode": 1,
>   "IsErroredOnProcessing": false,
>   "ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds": 0.973,
>   "SearchablePDFURL": ""
> }';
> ```

**I execute this also**

```
$array=json_decode($bb,true); 
echo $array->ParsedResults->TextOverlay->Lines->LineText;
```

**I try extract information from json data, but i can´t get works, i try with this :**

```
echo $array->ParsedResults->TextOverlay->Lines->LineText;
```

I try many different ways for show data but i can´t get show informations or extract values from tag WordText, always return me blank page and don´t show me nothing and i belive i do well, and i try also with loop for show all data and don´t works

```
foreach($array as $arrays)
{

echo $arrays->ParsedResults->TextOverlay;

}
```

**But i can´t get works, howewer some people can tell me what i do wrong for fix this, thank´s for the help, regards**

Answer (score 1):

You are decoding the JSON to an array, but trying to access it like an object.

There are two ways to decode a JSON with [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php):

**1- Decoding to array:**

```
$decodedArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

This way you will access JSON data as an array:

```
foreach($decodeArray as $element) {
    echo $element['something']['something'];
}
```

**2- Decoding to an object:**

```
$decodedObject = json_decode($jsonString, false);
```

Or

```
$decodedObject = json_decode($jsonString);
```

This way you will access like:

```
foreach($decodedObject as $element) {
   echo $element->something->something;
}
```

**EDIT: Accessing deep nested properties mentioned in the question**

You are trying to access the deep levels the wrong way. In you JSON schema, `ParseResults`, `Lines` and `Words` are arrays. That means you cannot access them directly like:

```
$element->ParsedResults->Overlay->Lines
```

To reach the deepest level and print `WordText`, you will can use some `foreach()`:

```
$decodedObject = json_decode($bb); 
foreach($decodedObject->ParsedResults as $result) {
    $lines = $result->Overlay->Lines;
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        foreach ($line->Words as $word) {
            echo($word->WordText . "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will print:

```
Amazon
€860.53
Marketplace
New
```

Comment: Close, `json_decode($jsonString);` without a second argument will actually decode to an object, not to an array.

Comment: Ooops! You're right! Answer updated. Thank you very much!

Comment: I try all you tell and don´t works nothing you can test : $decodedObject = json_decode($bb);

foreach($decodedObject as $element) 
{
$a=$element->ParsedResults->Overlay->Lines;

foreach ($a as $aa)
{

echo $aa->Words-WordText;

}


}

Comment: @AlfredoAguinFigueiro I edited the answer to cover your scenario. Hope it helps